# Selenium IDE does not record events from a server, but from disk

Tags: html, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-ide

I'm encountering an issue that **Selenium IDE seems not to record a specific event** on a real webserver.

However, if I **save the page** (including all resources) via firefox entirely **to disk**, open the saved file in the browser and try to record the same issue, **Selenium IDE now works correctly** and records the event as expected.

I'm not sure what is causing this behavior - maybe some race conditions inside Selenium IDE exists (latencies from a real webserver are higher than on a local file URL), or maybe it has something to do with URLs - but these are only quick guesses.

**Does anybody have some suggestions/best practices how to track down such kind of Selenium IDE issues?**

**UPDATE:**

**I figured out my root issue**, only with trial and error, but with succeess.
 **[I filed a bug at the selemium project](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3929)**.

The reason why it locally worked was a file not found after form submit which not happened at the serverside. It seems that the file not found error strangely prevented the bug from occuring.

**However, the main part of this question isn't really answered yet**, next time I still do not know how to quickly track down such issues. So for now, I'll keep it open.

Comment: Post an example. Give us a small html page, and a small Selenium IDE export, so we can try it and test it ourselves. There is no way at all to figure out what the issue is otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I have similar issue.  The Selenium IDE does not record anything from this website "http://suppliers.inwk.com". You may not have credentials to get login access, but if you can get the login page itself recorded in Selenum IDE, then I think we can come to the root cause, or atleast get a clue.